# How do I make a formula to take the sum of data corresponding to dates only in a 2-week time period?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

**Hi there,**

I'm new to Stack Overflow. I have a hobbyist-level knowledge of web coding (HTML, CSS, PHP, etc.) and making spreadsheets do things for me.

But, I can't seem to figure out how to do the following in Google Sheets:

*(First off, Sheet1 does simple calculations on a sheet linked to a Google Form with which a user inputs data on their work shifts.)*

1. Out of Sheet1, select only the date values in column A (Date) which fall on or between pay period start and end dates on Sheet2 (e.g. Sheet2!B2 [2014-09-28] and Sheet2!C2 [2014-10-11]), and
2. Then, for the date values in Sheet1 column A that are on or between Sheet2!B2 & Sheet2!C2, take the sum of the corresponding data in Sheet1 column B (Hours) (e.g. 2014-09-28 → 3.75, 2014-09-29 → 3.75 … 2014-10-05 → 4.00), and
3. Do the same for data in Sheet1 columns E & F (Tips & Deliveries).

Anyone know? Thanks!

**Screenshots of each sheet here:**

Sheet1

[Sheet1 http://4cm4k1.com/img/screenshot3.png](http://4cm4k1.com/img/screenshot3.png)

Sheet2

[Sheet2 http://4cm4k1.com/img/screenshot2.png](http://4cm4k1.com/img/screenshot2.png)

Google Forms Sheet

[Google Forms Sheet http://4cm4k1.com/img/screenshot1.png](http://4cm4k1.com/img/screenshot1.png)

Comment: @pnuts Excel formulas/knowledge may apply here, although formatting & syntax are not exactly the same between Excel & Google Sheets. **Edit:** I'm new, so if you don't think it should be tagged with [excel], I'd appreciate feedback.

Comment: @pnuts I removed the [excel] tag, and submitted my solution as an answer. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In D2 of Sheet2, I wrote the formula:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!B:B, 'Sheet1'!A:A, ">="&B2, 'Sheet1'!A:A, "<="&C2)
```